# Simulate a panorama using 6 cube faces

Tags: python

I have the 6 cube face images required to render a panorama. I am trying to see if it is possible to use Blender to use these images as the textures for a cube and then place a camera inside the cube to generate a video of the panorama (by rotating the camera). If this is possible, I intend to use Blender's Python API to automate this.

Full disclosure: I have no prior experience with Blender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if its possible to automate it

But It can be done manually by

Making the Normals face inwards,

UV unwrapping the cube,

mapping the textures

move the camera to the center

and render a 360 panoramic
http://regusmartin.deviantart.com/art/Panoramic-Rendering-in-Blender-468232790

Answer (score 0):

If your question is: Is it possible?
Can't help you with the scripting but it's definitely possible to model the scenario.

You should easily be able to find out how to make a box and unwrap it. You may need to adjust the UV's to get the textures right. It may be easier to make a big texture of the 6 images.
Make sure you flip the normals to point inwards.

Comment: Thank you! I chose @eromod's answer because it linked to a guide (which contained pictures :D).